# scala downcasting with generics

Tags: scala, generics, downcast

I'm looking for help with the following problem:

```
case class A(val name: String)
class B(name: String) extends A(name)
class Base[T <: A](param: T)
class SubClass[T <: B](param: T)

object Factory {
  def create[T <: A](param: T) = {
    param.name match {
       case "something" => new Base(param)
       case "something else" => new SubClass(param)
    }
  }
}
```

The factory doesn't compile because of the mismatch between the param Subclass is expecting (T :< B) and the definition of T in create which isT :< A. Is there a clean solution for this or do I need to downcast on the call to the Subclass constructor? how would the downcast look like?

Just to be clear - when Subclass is contructed with param, param is indeed of T<: B.

Thanks.

Comment: `T:<A` is a typo. I guess you mean `T <: A`.

Comment: `class B extends A` doesn't compile for a start...

Comment: thanks for your comments senia and luigi. typos fixed. It compiles apart from the issue in question.

Comment: @user1467422: you should remove `val` from `class B(val name: String) extends A(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you match on param first?

```
param match {
  case b : B => ...
  case a : A => ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiles and runs OK if you supply the type parameter:

```
case "something else" => new SubClass[T](param)
```

Whether it *should* compile is questionable, as it will give a `ClassCastException` at runtime if this match occurs and `T` is not a `B`.

Cleaner solution is to match on type as Daniel says.

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation as to why it does typecheck?